# How to perform a Bitwise Operator on a byte array in C#

Tags: c#, xna

I am using C# and `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio`;

I have managed to record some audio into a `byte[]` array and I am able to play it back.

The audio comes in as `8 bit` unsigned data, and I would like to convert it into `16 bit` mono signed audio so I can read the frequency what not.

I have read a few places that for sound sampling you perform a `Bitwise Operator Or` and `shift the bits 8 places`.

I have performed the code as follows;

```
soundArray[i] = (short)(buffer[i] | (buffer[i + 1] << 8));
```

What I end up with is a lot of negative data.

From my understanding it would mostly need to be in the positive and would represent a wave length of data.

Any suggestions or help greatly appreciated,

Cheers.

MonkeyGuy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This combines **two** 8-bit unsigned integers into one 16-bit signed integer:

```
soundArray[i] = (short)(buffer[i] | (buffer[i + 1] << 8));
```

I think what you might want is to simply scale **each** 8-bit unsigned integer to a 16-bit signed integer:

```
soundArray[i] = (short)((buffer[i] - 128) << 8);
```

[image]

Comment: Still getting quite a few negative but a lot of positives now and they're quite high in the range up to the 32,000 mark.

The Sample Bit Rate is apparently 16000hz.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting the byte to short before shifting?

Comment: You can't shift bytes. If you use `<<` on a byte, it's automatically converted to an `int`/`Int32`.

Comment: Yes I do it right before the bitwise conversion on;
soundArray[i] = (short)(buffer[i] | (buffer[i + 1] << 8));